# Does facebook open graph can replace a database ? (web )

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am pretty new to the Facebook API. I tried to read the online documentation but I am missing something. Is it possible to use the open graph to store information?

Basically, would it be possible to create a website and use some custom object type to store data instead of having my own database? (e.g. storing game score, survey response...)

Then, the website would just have to read those data from the FB open graph, manipulate them, and send them back via the open graph api.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook graph is used to query facebooks data, you can't establish your own data structures on the graph as far as I am aware.